# How do I get Windows to recognize our exe as a communication app

Tags: windows, audio

Windows has a well documented/[much complained](https://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly) about feature where it will reduce the volume of applications when it thinks that the pc is being used for communication.

We build such an app for audio communication however Windows keeps lowering the volume of our own app whilst it's being used so you can barely hear the other party. There must be some way to tell Windows not to do this, for example Skype does not suffer - perhaps a registry key or property on the exe?

I'm unable to find anything documenting how this functionality works from a developer point of view.